# Flutter device daemon #1 error - Can't run any apps on mobile device

Tags: git, android-studio, flutter

I am not able to run any apps at all at present, as my setup is giving me the following error:

```
Flutter device daemon
  Flutter device daemon #1: process exited during startup. Exit code: 1, stderr:
  'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
```

This manifests itself by showing my device list as constantly "loading..." and never finding my device.

Flutter doctor -v from command line:

[image]

Flutter doctor -v from Gitbash, because I have git, despite the path error.

[image]

Git is located at X:\flutter\bin\mingit\cmd\git.exe which is included in my PATH variable.

I have tried reinstalling the SDK, Flutter and Android Studio from scratch to resolve this so far, but I can't shake it.

Hope there is a pro out there that can help.

Comment: `'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` it seems that when you running the flutter command it try to located a file with `where` command. I don't think there is a `where` command in Windows, except when you have a cygwin installed. Does this problem is encountered after you upgrade the flutter?

Comment: Hi mate, thank you for your response.   Flutter is fully upgraded and I even reinstalled it from scratch to try and resolve this error.   The error is still there.   Does gitbash use cygwin?   This is ringing a bell, wonder if having this installed is causing all my issues?

Comment: I've searched for gitbash and cygwin love-hate relationship but none found anything related with your problem. But probably the gitbash messing your flutter because it add its path to your environment. Does uninstalling gitbash can solve your problem? Have you test it?

Comment: I will test it tonight when I get home, thank you for the advice

Comment: Hoping that you'll solved the problem tonight ;)

Comment: I uninstalled git completely from my machine, then reinstalled it from scratch.  Tested again and I am getting exactly the same error.   Have now reinstalled Android Studio, Flutter, SDK, and Git and nothing has changed at all  :(

Comment: I have noticed that if I run flutter doctor from c:\windows\system32 it seems to work fine.    If I run it from anywhere else I get the 'where' is not recognised error.....  this could be the key, but I still don't know what could be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is bit late but this has resolved the issue.
Make sure , you have downloaded the following-:
flutter
git

Next , is to add the following in user Path Variables [ Environment Variables<Users<Path ]

C:\src\flutter\bin

Now, add them in System Path Variables. [Environment Variables< System< Path]

1. C:\Program Files\Git\cmd      // git path
2. C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
   // power shell path as if you not set this it will show error like error powershell executable not found
3. C:\Windows\System32

Comment: In my case, it was the dartSDK setting path not right,  correct the SDK path works for me :]

Answer (score 1):

After long time working on this problem I found 100% working solution to this problem:

After installing Git when we opens Android studio or Vs Code gets pop ups that:

flutter devices daemon or flutter daemon crashed

The solution is.

After you install Git

1. Go to the path where you install Git
2. Open Git directory
3. Go to mingw64 directory

For me    C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin

4. Then go to bin and copy that path
5. Add that path in environment variable
6. Restart your IDE if opened already

And your problem will be completely solved
Remember me in your prayers Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to fix this problem:

1. I downloaded and installed mingw64 - it's a bash terminal for Windows.
2. I set the Shell Path in Android Studio - Preferences - Tools - Terminal to "C:\Users\my.user.name\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\git-bash.exe"
3. Closed the project and opened it again
4. Clicked in the "Terminal" pane which launched my git-bash terminal instead of the default cmd.exe terminal found in Windows
5. Now my device was available and it wasn't saying "Loading..." anymore
6. However, the build would not work - it got stuck in "Initializing gradle..."
7. Set my terminal back to cmd.exe and closed the project
8. Re-opened the project, this time with the default terminal. I expected to get the "Loading..." error again, but miraculously the device was still visible.
9. Ran the app
10. App worked, appeared on my phone.

You can try to see if it works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem regarding flutter device deamon even though I had sdk and Android studio all connected and running properly the day before. i resolved this issue   just by running intellij as an administrator and then it recognised my external device.
hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by removing git on windows 10

Or you can update environment path variable as ordered list that git is after flutter git.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue on a Mac, turns out I mistakenly installed Android Studio for Apple Chip when my Mac had an Intel chip, so Android Studio installed but couldn't run anything. Uninstalling the wrong version and installing the correct one reverted everything back to normal.